# Keycloak and Vertx

Tags: ionic-framework, vert.x, keycloak

We are implementing RESTful service and the entire backend application using Vert.x. These API's are consumed by a hybrid mobile app (developed using Ionic / angularjs). We are using Keycloak for user management and also authentication and authorization on the app.

My question is, how can I use Keycloak to also protect (authenticate and authorize for the same set of users) my RESTful service access which is implemented using Vert.x. Any example implementation would be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

We wrote a custom Vert.x auth provider using the Keycloak core library to solve this exact problem (the Vert.x JWT library doesn't work with the Keycloak JWT tokens - arguably we should have improved the Vert.x library instead). I'll see if I can get permission to open source the library.

Answer (score 0):

So, if i understand correctly, you need one authentication entry point for user in mobile app and in REST service. If i am right, you can use JWT. When user will authenticate with Keycloak he will receive jwt with roles and user information. This token you can put into request for REST service and your Service will know who is the user and what roles he have. Please see https://jwt.io/